# ¿Por qué es "bajón" antónimo de "subidón"?

Tags: antónimos, aumentativos

Fulanito está de *subidón* pero Menganito está de *bajón*.

Según el DLE, [*subidón*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YWuWZ9B) es aumentativo de *subida* y [*bajón*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4pC4x0t) de *baja*.

Entre las acepciones de *baja*, la única que se acerca a la de este aumentativo es "disminución del precio, valor y estimación de algo". Sin embargo, como aumentativo, es "descenso brusco e importante", sin que sea necesariamente del precio, etc. Hay que tener en cuenta que *baja* y *alza* se aplican al precio, valor, estimación, mientras que *estar de subidón* o *de bajón* se refieren al ánimo principalmente.

Entre *subida* y *subidón* hay coherencia, puesto que en ninguna de las dos definiciones se especifica el tipo de cosa que sube.

Otra incoherencia está en los sustantivos escogidos como antónimos para aumentarlos: el de *subida* es *bajada* y el de *baja* es *alza*. Ni *alzón* ni *bajadón* están en el diccionario, aunque creo que son construcciones ajustadas a las normas de construcción del español (no todas las palabras resultado de todas las combinaciones de modificadores de palabras tienen entrada propia en el diccionario). Al menos, [tan ajustadas como *bajón* y *subidón*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/cu%C3%A1ndo-un-aumentativo-cambia-el-g%C3%A9nero-del-sustantivo).

¿Hay alguna razón para que este par de antónimos tenga una construcción de procedencia diferente?

Comment: +1 por tu primera pregunta, bien expuesta e interesante. Para hacerla redonda, intenta poner un título más descriptivo : )

Comment: No sé si así el título es más interesante. Si tienes claro cómo edita el título a tu antojo. Tal vez debería separar las dos preguntas. A mí me gustaría saber si hay algún patrón que se me escapa para construir los aumentativos de una forma o de otra.

Comment: Para mí el título debe ser un resumen y una llamada a la acción: _¿Por qué...?_, _¿Cómo...?_, _¿Qué diferencia...?_, pero es algo personal. Y sí, si son dos preguntas, mejor dos publicaciones diferentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Llevo cortocircuitado desde que hiciste la pregunta, y sin embargo ahora que me he puesto a buscar la explicación creo que es mucho más sencilla de lo que aparenta. Se prefirió el uso de *bajón* antes que de *bajadón* porque la palabra [ya existía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4p7NVZz%7C4pC4x0t):

> **bajón**
>
> Del aum. de *bajo*.
>
> 1. m. Instrumento musical de viento, antecesor del fagot, usado especialmente para interpretar música sacra.
> 2. m. p. us. bajo (‖ persona que tiene voz de bajo).
> 3. m. y f. bajonista.

Nótese que, en este caso, el aumentativo es de *bajo*, lo cual además ayuda a explicar por qué el aumentativo es masculino: porque la palabra original también lo es. Dado que este uso de *bajón* parece previo, por economía del lenguaje se podría explicar que se usara esa misma palabra en vez de acuñar una nueva (que sería *bajadón*) como aumentativo de *baja* o incluso de *bajada*.

A partir de aquí, la gente simplemente empezó a usar el aumentativo para indicar un descenso brusco de cualquier tipo: de salud, de estado de ánimo, de cantidad de algo, de lo que sea. Esto se podría explicar porque el aumentativo se podría considerar como una sustantivización del verbo *bajar*. Y claro, la RAE cumple su deber y refleja en el diccionario esos usos, porque a fin de cuentas el lenguaje lo hacemos nosotros, y no al revés.

Comment: Es probable que sea así. A no ser que alguien proporcione una respuesta más verosímil, [para mí, queda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4V9j2-zBrQ#t=09m52s). (Ya disculparéis tanta referencia luthierana, pero es que tienen una cita para cada ocasión).

Comment: ¡Todo enlace a un vídeo de Les Luthiers tiene un +1! :)