# ¿Cuándo un aumentativo cambia el género del sustantivo?

Tags: género, aumentativos

Al respecto de [¿Por qué es bajón antónimo de subidón?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17354/incoherencias-en-los-ant%C3%B3nimos-subid%C3%B3n-y-baj%C3%B3n), me surge la duda de por qué a veces el aumentativo de un nombre femenino mantiene su género, como *señora*/*señorona*, mientras que otras cambia, como *subida*/*subidón* o *baja*/*bajón*.

¿Cuál es la regla, si es que la hay, para diferenciar unos casos de otros? ¿Es generalizable a otros sufijos aumentativos distintos de -*ón*/-*ona*?

Comment: Uhms, por lo que [dice Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Aumentativo) _Los aumentativos en -on, salvo cuando se refieren a persona, suelen ser masculinos aunque deriven de una palabra femenina_. Ese _suelen_ me induce a buscar ejemplos donde no ocurre, pero no caigo en ninguno ahora mismo.

Comment: La verdad es que ese _suelen_ mosquea un poco. ¿Hay alguna excepción?

Comment: Pues pensándolo bien no debería: si son masculinos acabarán en _ón_, mientras que los femeninos lo harán en _ona_.

Comment: Se me ocurre un caso inverso, tal vez un poco rebuscado: _temblor_ es masculino y el aumentativo sería _temblona_ (en el diccionario, _temblona_ es adj. pero existe la expresión [_hacer un pordiosero la **temblona**_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZPNx5bv)).

Comment: Sí, aunque de todos modos la frase _Los aumentativos en -on, (...) suelen ser masculinos_ yo la interpreto como que tales palabras acabadas en _on_ son las que suelen ser masculinas. Las que terminan en _ona_ serían caso aparte. O así entiendo yo la frase, vaya :)

Comment: Puede ser al revés, el cambio de género también cambia el tamaño de las cosas. Un cesto es una cesta grande. Una barca es un barco pequeño. Una jarra es más grande que un jarro. Un puerto es como una puerta pero grande.

Comment: Al menos, hay una excepción (del aumentativo en -_on_): _casa/casona_. Con otros sufijos aumentativos simplemente no es cierto (_grasa/grasota_, p. ej.). Por cierto, ¿cuál es la fiabilidad de Wikilengua como fuente? Yo mismo, ayer, corregí una errata que había en la página y supongo que también otros pueden poner lo que les parezca (con razón o sin ella).

Comment: En otros sitios de España no sé, pero en Andalucía se usa mucho el femenino _bajona_, sobre todo cuando se refiere al estado de ánimo: _Tengo una bajona tremenda_. E incluso el aumentativo del aumentativo: _¡No veas qué bajonazo!_

Comment: Parece que la página de Wikilengua no es muy exhaustiva. ¿No hay un artículo de la RAE al respecto? Yo no lo he encontrado, al menos.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy casi seguro que no hay regla fija para eso. El encontrar tantos "suelen" en las explicaciones lo está insinuando.

Citando a [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Aumentativo#Formaci.C3.B3n), en cuanto a la formación del aumentativo:

> no puede darse regla fija, a pesar de ser muy inferior su número al de los diminutivos.
>   Es de observar, sin embargo, que la forma del aumentativo se determina por la idea que nos proponemos dar a entender variando la terminación del positivo; y que, al contrario, la terminación diminutiva se decide por la estructura material de la palabra positiva cuya significación modificamos.
>   De aquí el reducirse a pocos los sufijos aumentativos; porque no basta para aumentar simplemente la idea del positivo; azo, para expresar lo disforme o extremado; y acho y ote, para lo monstruoso o ridículo:
>   hombrón, hombrazo, hombracho, hombrote

Además te dejo lo que "dice" la [RAE](http://www.rae.es/publicaciones/211-aumentativos-diminutivos-despectivos-y-superlativos), que no es mucho.

Una cosa más. Esto es opinión pero igual te lo digo; no se cuánto puede aportarle el "manejo" de los aumentativos a tu carácter porque no contienen precisión descriptiva. Y lo último, creo que apoyando a la no existencia de reglas, si tú me preguntabas el aumentativo de "señora", nunca hubiese dicho "señorona". Podría haber pensado en "señoraza".

Comment: No hay mucha información al respecto y mis dudas sobre Wikilengua las expuse arriba. Lo de "Las posibilidades de variación de los correspondientes sufijos, así como la gran capacidad expresiva de los términos formados, hacen muy discutible todo inventario de esta posibilidad morfológica" se refieren a las reglas de formación de aum. y dim. (que sería para hacer una pregunta aparte). Mi pregunta era sobre el cambio de género (que parece ser que solo ocurre con -on) y sus posibles excepciones. Tampoco me refería a qué sufijo sería más apropiado utilizar con _señora_ u otro nombre. +1, eso sí.