# ¿Cuáles serian los adjetivos más adecuados para caracterizar de un aeda o un bardo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Revisaba el término *Aedo* y, queriendo citar las condiciones de alguien que lo fuera, encuentro que *aédico* mas que a la poesía, hace referencia a [cierto mosquito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aedes_aegypti). Igualmente busco un adjetivo para la palabra *Bardo*.

No sé si de estas palabras en particular se desprenden adjetivos (quizá no tan fáciles de encontrar) que sirvan para describir, más allá de los 'simples' poético, lírico o épico (que son los primeros que vienen a la cabeza, tal vez por contar con su correspondiente sustantivo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que podemos apostar por "bárdico", aunque no se encuentre en el DLE.

[Diccionario enciclopédico gallego-castellano](https://books.google.es/books?id=ff_7pP1vPYMC&lpg=PA327&ots=-xrI6j_0C_&dq=%22bardico%22%20%22bardos%22&pg=PA327#v=onepage&q=%22bardico%22%20%22bardos%22&f=false).

[Diccionario normativo galego-castelán](https://books.google.es/books?id=FoBE9EDhqlAC&lpg=PA130&ots=FHyInMwlg8&dq=%22bardico%22%20%22bardos%22&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=%22bardico%22%20%22bardos%22&f=false).

Respecto a su ausencia en el diccionario "oficial", nunca viene mal recordar ([aunque ellos digan que no es necesario](http://dle.rae.es/?t=/docs/advertencias.html)) que...

> (...) las posibilidades de formación de nuevas palabras (...) son
>   amplísimas, y no todos los resultados posibles los recoge el
>   Diccionario, sino únicamente aquellos que han alcanzado cierta
>   reiteración en el uso. No es necesario señalar que la ausencia de un
>   derivado o un compuesto posible no implica su ilegitimidad.

Así que usemos *bárdico*, *bárdica*, etc. sin miedo: son términos bien formados, acordes con el "genio del idioma", como dice Álex Grijelmo, que satisfacen de forma sencilla una necesidad expresiva e [incluso pueden encontrarse en el registro escrito](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=b%C3%A1rdico%2Bb%C3%A1rdica%2Bb%C3%A1rdicos%2Bb%C3%A1rdicas&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=10&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28b%C3%A1rdico%20%2B%20b%C3%A1rdica%20%2B%20b%C3%A1rdicos%20%2B%20b%C3%A1rdicas%29%3B%2Cc0).

[image: Uso de "bárdico" y derivados en libros]

### Edito para añadir un ejemplo a petición del *OP*

Ya se ve en el gráfico del Ngram (me resultan curiosos los [subidones](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17354/12991) en el uso de estas palabras alrededor de 1890 y 1925 aprox.) y puede hacerse una [búsqueda genérica de estos términos en la búsqueda de libros de Google](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22b%C3%A1rdico%22+OR+%22b%C3%A1rdica%22+OR+%22b%C3%A1rdicos%22+OR+%22b%C3%A1rdicas%22), pero añadiremos [una cita, que incluye una cita con una referencia, de un libro más o menos reciente](https://books.google.es/books?id=lkLP2rnZzQMC&lpg=PA168&dq=%22b%C3%A1rdico%22%20OR%20%22b%C3%A1rdica%22%20OR%20%22b%C3%A1rdicos%22%20OR%20%22b%C3%A1rdicas%22&hl=es&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> *La función **bárdica**.* La idea de la televisión como poeta lírico, juglar contemporáneo, la sugiere `(sic)` Fiske y Hartley (1978), que proponen
>   encuadrar las posibilidades fabulísticas mediáticas que hemos visto
>   antes en una función que los dos autores, precisamente, definen como
>   «**bárdica**». «El bardo —explican Casetti y de Chio (1998: 265)— es el
>   que canta las gestas de una comunidad; registra sus eventos y las
>   preocupaciones incluso mínimas, las transforma en versos y las vuelve
>   a ofrecer para el disfrute de todos. Es decir, el bardo trabaja en y
>   para la creación de un patrimonio común». Del mismo modo, la función
>   **bárdica** de la televisión consistirá «en hacerse mediadora de
>   lenguajes, en ponerse en el centro de la cultura, en reconducir las
>   dificultades de la vida social a valores y símbolos compartidos por
>   los miembros de la comunidad» (Casetti y de Chio, 1998).

Federico Boni, ([*Teorías de los medios de comunicación*](https://books.google.es/books?isbn=8437070961), 2008), pág. 168.

Comment: ¿podrías citar algún ejemplo, para aceptar mejor la respuesta?